# Change Zombie window X properties from Iconic state to Normal state

Tags: x11

Mathematica sets its *Documentation Center* as an iconic window according to `xprop`. I think this state might be the culprit for making this window a zombie window, not focusable by the mouse on my window manager. Can I change the window state to normal using some X tools?

Here is the output from `xprop`:

```
_NET_WM_DESKTOP(CARDINAL) = 3
_NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST_COUNTER(CARDINAL) = 25191353
_NET_WM_USER_TIME(CARDINAL) = 46824074
_NET_WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "Mathematica - Wolfram Mathematica"
_NET_WM_ICON(CARDINAL) =    Icon (31 x 32):

                    ░              
                    ▒              
                   ░▒              
           ░       ▒▒░      ░      
           ░▒░    ░▒▓▒     ▒░      
            ▒▒▒░ ░▒▓▓▓░  ░▒▒       
            ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▒▓▓▒░       
            ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▒▒░       
            ▒▒▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▒▒▒        
       ▒░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▒▒▒▒▒▒░       
        ▒▒▒▒▒░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░      
         ▒▒▒▒▒░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▒▒▒▒▒░ 
         ░▓▓▓▒░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▒▒▒░   
          ▒▓▓▒░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▒▒▒░    
          ▒▓▒░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▒▒░     
         ░▓▓░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▓▓▓▒▒      
        ░▓▒░░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▓▓▓▒      
       ▒▓▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒░     
     ░▒▒▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒░    
          ░▒▒░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░   
            ▒▓▒░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░▒▒░  
            ▒▒▓▒░░░░▒▓▓▓▓▓▒        
            ▒▒▒▓░░░▒▓▓▓▓▒▒▒        
           ░▒▒▒░▒░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒        
           ░░    ░▒▒▒░  ░▒▒        
                 ▒▒▒░     ▒░       
                 ▒▒▒       ░       
                  ▒░               
                  ▒                
                  ░                



XdndAware(ATOM) = BITMAP
_MOTIF_DRAG_RECEIVER_INFO(_MOTIF_DRAG_RECEIVER_INFO) = 0x6c, 0x0, 0x5, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 WM_CLIENT_LEADER(WINDOW): window id # 0x1800003
_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 2882
_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL
_MOTIF_WM_HINTS(_MOTIF_WM_HINTS) = 0x3, 0x3e, 0x7e, 0x0, 0x0 WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_DELETE_WINDOW, WM_TAKE_FOCUS,
_NET_WM_PING, _NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST WM_NAME(STRING) = "Mathematica - Wolfram Mathematica" WM_LOCALE_NAME(STRING) = "en_US.UTF-8" WM_CLASS(STRING) = "XMathematica" WM_HINTS(WM_HINTS):       Client accepts input or input focus: True       Initial state is Iconic State.      bitmap id # to use for icon: 0x180637b      window id # of group leader: 0x1800003 WM_NORMAL_HINTS(WM_SIZE_HINTS):      user specified location: 277, 12        program specified location: 277, 12         user specified size: 725 by 775         program specified size: 725 by 775      program specified minimum size: 56 by 177       window gravity: NorthWest WM_CLIENT_MACHINE(STRING) = "wdkrnls" WM_COMMAND(STRING) = { "/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/Binaries/Linux-x86-64/Mathematica", "-topDirectory", "/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0" }
```

And here is a screenshot showing the border of this window:

[image]

Comment: The window manager is responsibly for declaring some windows to be unfocusable. You need to tell your window manager that this window may be focused. What window manager are you using?

Comment: I am using [herbstluftwm](http://wwwcip.cs.fau.de/~re06huxa/herbstluftwm/) but it seems this is also a problem on [i3wm](http://forums.wolfram.com/student-support/topics/109180) as well. Both window managers are static tilers with the capability sending windows to a "floating" layer.